# Error in (.format.s.statistics.list != "p25") && (.format.s.statistics.list != : 'length = 7' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I am doing a regression analysis based on results on a survey, where I coded some of them as

```
firstStepMutatedData <- mydata %>% 
    mutate(republican = ifelse((pid == 2), 1, 0),            
    conservative = ifelse((ideology >= 8), 1, 0),
    votedTrump = ifelse((Q38 == 2),1,0),
    white = ifelse((raceXethnic == "white & not hisp"),1,0),
    asian = ifelse((raceXethnic == "asian & not hisp" | raceXethnic == "asian & hisp"),1,0),
    otherRace = ifelse((raceXethnic != "white & not hisp" & raceXethnic != "asian & not hisp" & raceXethnic != "asian & hisp" ),1,0),
    wantMove1year = ifelse((Q17 <= 2),1,0),
    wantMove5year = ifelse((Q18 <= 2),1,0),
    jobProsp = ifelse((Q8 == 1), 1, 0),
    costProsp = ifelse((Q9 == 1), 1, 0),
    qualityProsp = ifelse((Q10 == 1), 1, 0),
    taxProsp = ifelse((Q11 == 2), 1, 0),
    schoolGovtProsp = ifelse((Q12 == 1), 1, 0),
    peopleProsp = ifelse((Q13 == 1), 1, 0),
    politicalProsp = ifelse((Q14 == 1), 1, 0),
    crimeProsp = ifelse((Q15 == 2), 1, 0),
    childrenLifeProsp = ifelse((Q16 == 1), 1, 0),
    buyHomeCA = ifelse((Q29 == 1),1,0),
    buyHomeElsewhere = ifelse((Q29 ==2),1,0),
    notBuyHome = ifelse((Q29==3),1,0))`
```

and then I ran several lm regressions, an example:

```
    demoVote1 <- lm(votedTrump ~ republican + conservative, firstStepMutatedData)
    demoVote2 <- lm(votedTrump ~ republican + conservative + white, firstStepMutatedData)
    stargazer(demoVote1, demoVote2, type = "text")
```

And I saw the following error message for all of them:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhN1A.png)

What might be the problem?

Comment: Some things that you could do to improve this post: (1) give **reproducible** code that others could run to encounter your error. Try starting with one of the built-in R data sets and see if you get similar errors. (2) Have your actual error somewhere in the body of your post, not just the title (3) Double check that your images were attached correctly.

I'm just trying to protect you from downvotes here. It takes courage to go from lurker to active participant in the site and some folks on this board can be cruel to newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error. For me and I assume for you, the issue was a breaking update in R that caused stargazer 5.2.2 to throw an error. The stargazer maintainers fixed the issue with the 5.2.3 release.

If you just **update your stargazer package** `install.packages('stargazer')`, then you should be good to go!

Please see this post from the R help server for more info.  https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2023-June/477522.html